# What is the value of this infinite sum?

Tags: summation

Take the sum $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n -1}$. I plugged it into Wolfram alpha, and it converges to a value around $1.606 \dots$ but wolfram didn't spit out any nice closed form. Is there an exact value for this sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No closed form (in terms of the familiar functions of high school algebra and intro Calculus) is known. The number is sometines called the Erdos-Borwein constant, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Borwein_constant).

Answer (score 1):

In general the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1-a^k}=\frac{\psi_{1/a}(1)+\ln(a-1)+\ln\frac 1 a}{\ln a}$$

where $\psi_q(z)$ is [the $q$-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).

Therefore

$$\sum _{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k-1}=1-\frac{\psi_{1/2}(1)}{\log 2}$$